# BlackBerry Webwork App turns device OFF

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I developed a Webwork/HTML5 app and I tested it on Ripley Simultar, and a couple of BB OS5 and BB OS6 simulators.

Now I want to test it on real BB OS5 device, I signed the app and I installed via OTAInstall (.jad) .

When I run the app, sometimes it turns my BB off, and I have to turn it on again.

any ideas why is it happening ?

I already asked on BB forums but I didn't get any response.